# Plain TeX: missing symbol

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling, plain-tex

I've tried to compile (both `pdfTeX` and `XeTeX`) simple code:

```
☺
\bye
```

But in result I have a plain page, without anything. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you loaded a font with the appropriate symbol present?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In XeTeX you need a font with this character:

```
\font\dejavusans="DejaVu Sans" at 10pt
{\dejavusans ☺}
\bye
```

Same for PDFTeX, but good luck with setting up fonts there.